# Least common multiples of orders

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I´ve just started my abstract algebra course, and it´s my first course in years... And I find it really hard! So I hope someone could help me with a problem we have to solve until next class.

"Let $G$ be a group and suppose $a$ and $b$ are elements of $G$ of finite order such that

$ab = ba$,

and that for every integer $m, a^m$ is not a power of $b$ and

for every nonzero integer $k, b^k$ is not a power of $a$.

Show that the order of $ab$ is the least common multiple of the order of a and the order of $b$."

I really have no idea where to start, and I don´t even know where to look in my textbook. If someone could please help me and explain this in an easy way, I would be grateful!!! :)

Comment: First, it seems your condition of $a^m$ not being a power of $b$ is missing the non-zero part that is present for $k$. Some hints: In order to show that a positive integer $x$ is the order of the given element $ab$, you have to prove two things: a) $(ab)^x=e$ and b) $(ab)^y \neq e$ for all positive $y < x$, where $e$ is the neutral element of the group. Start with proving a), which is the simpler of the 2 parts.

Comment: First things first, Welcome to the community. That being said, I suggest you look into tutorials on how to use LaTeX, or other subscripts for professional writing. This will help you get more people who will want to respond to your post.

Comment: The statement you wrote is vacuously true: there exist no elements $a$ and $b$ of a group satisfying your hypotheses.  It should presumably say instead that $a^m$ is not a power of $b$ _unless_ $a^m=1$, and similarly for $b^k$.

Comment: Secondly you are dealing with an abelian group. This has certain properties you can use.  From your assumptions we know there is at least 3 different elements in the group $e$, $a$, and $b$, where $e$ is the identity of the group $ae=a$. Now look at the sub groups $A$ and $B$ of $G$  where the only elements of $A$ are multiples of $a$ and $e$ and likewise for $e,b\in B$.  What does it mean for a group to have a finite order?

Comment: Especially for these questions (LCM of orders, etc...), it is very advisable to have a little working practise on the **permutation group**. I advise you to see the following text (http://math.mit.edu/~mckernan/Teaching/12-13/Spring/18.703/l_5.pdf).

Comment: @EricWofsey Not true!  Let $G$ be defined as $(\mathbb R, *)$ if $a=2$ and $b=8$ there exists a $k$ and $m$ such that $a^m=b^k$ namely $m=3$ and $k=1$ so $a^m \neq 1$.

Comment: @Sentinel135: I don't know what that has to do with what I wrote.  I'm just saying that there does not exist any group $G$ with elements $a$ and $b$ of finite order such that $a^m$ is never a power of $b$ and $b^k$ is never a power of $a$.

Comment: @EricWofsey ok that makes more sense. I honestly thought you meant that there didn't exist elements $a,b\in G$ such that $a^m=b^k$. That would contradict $G$ being a group. Just keep in mind that not all identities of abelian groups are $1$ some, like the modular groups have $0$ or $[0]$ as their identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to show that $o(ab) = lcm(o(a), o(b))$

let $n = o(ab)$

so. $(ab)^n = e$

since $ab = ba$,

$e = (ab)^n = ab. ab.ab...ab = a^nb^n$

now since $a^ m \neq b^l$ for any $m,l \in \mathbb{Z}$

$\implies a^n = b^n = e $

thus $ o(a)|n$ and $o(b)|n$ thus, $lcm(o(a), o(b)) | n$

But now since, $(ab)^{lcm(o(a), o(b))} = a^{lcm(o(a), o(b))}b^{lcm(o(a), o(b))} = e.e = e \implies  n|{lcm(o(a), o(b))}$

Thus $n = {lcm(o(a), o(b))}$